# Custom OnChange() trigger (googlesheet) with a specific range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, eventtrigger, google-sheets-api

I wanted to know if it's possible to trigger a function when there is a change in a specific column.

I would like to run a function when my appSheet add a new row in the column "S".

PS : I have never used trigger function in the past :/ so i don't even know how to create a custom one.

Thx for the help,

Regis

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) on bound scripts.

For example you're on your spreadsheet file:

Click Tools -> Script Editor.

This will open scripts page. Place this simple code and save it.

```
function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
    ui.alert("Hello, you\'re changing something!");
}
```

To activate this showPrompt function everytime you're changing something on the spreadsheet, go to:

Resources -> All your triggers -> Add a new trigger and copy this setup. Then Save.

[image]

Go back to your spreadsheet, refresh and try to write or erase something on the cells. A prompt will trigger. Check the [Class SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()) for additional info.

This is just a basic demo of onChange. You will have to modify it and use it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In a spreadsheet, when you add a row, it gets added to all columns. I'm not sure what you mean by  adding only to column 'S'. To detect a new row, use OnChange() trigger and get the information from the range field in the 'e' object passed to it. Read the docs here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events